# C#: How do I use HTTP authentication when making a SOAP call?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, soap, http-headers

So I'm trying to make a SOAP call to a webservice that uses HTTP authentication. I added a web reference in Visual Studio which generated a wrapper class for me. Here is the example code for how I'm making the call:

```
 var prox = new WebserviceNamespace.WebService();
 prox.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 prox.PreAuthenticate = true;
 var resp = prox.webMethod(null, null);
```

That last line throws an 'Authentication Failure' message.

I used wireshark to check if it was attempting to add basic authentication to the HTTP packet and it doesn't look like it is. Here is wireshark output:

```
 POST /cms/services/WebService HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.34209)\r\n
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo7e/OYIGV2VDs7nYMO5QmegAAAAAWxFxk5NzcUSF5zGIxQ1REwb488ITippOiEKaDSmuFDkACQAA\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n
SOAPAction: ""\r\n
Host: sub.domain.com\r\n
Content-Length: 343\r\n
Expect: 100-continue\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
\r\n
[Full request URI: http://sub.domain.com/cms/services/WebService3.0]
[HTTP request 2/2]
[Response in frame: 265321]eXtensible Markup Language
<?xml
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <webMethod
            xmlns="WebService">
            <in0 xsi:nil="true"/>
            <in1
                xsi:nil="true"/>
            </webMethod>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I was expecting to see a line like this for HTTP authentication:

```
Authorization: Basic SUNOOnNwc3pK
```

Would anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out. This very tiny article held the key for me: http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/at3/Forcing-basic-http-authentication-for-HttpWebReq.html

Basically the Credentials property is only used if the server challenges your request. If the server doesn't challenge it could just fail (as was happening to me). What I had to do was edit the auto-generated proxy class, adding this code to it (inspired by the link above):

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        String authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        return request;
    }
```

With that in place, I'm no longer getting Authentication errors!

Comment: You little RIPPER! Thank you very much for posting this, after hours of trying to get my request to work, adding those few lines of code (and entering my own username and password of course) make it all work!
Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou! :-)